# Can a dragonborn sorcerer designed to recharge her breath choose to fail a save against ongoing damage?

Tags: dnd-4e

Does a character have to do a saving throw at the end of his turn or can he or she choose to keep an effect active on them?  Will my idea below work as intended?

I'm looking into making a dragonborn dragon magic sorcerer with the following (all from phb-dragonborns):

Ninefold Master Paragon Path:
Breath Expertise (lvl 11): Your dragon breath is considered an arcane power belonging to each of your arcane classes.  If you are wielding an implement you can use for your arcane powers, you can add the implement's enhancement bonus to the damage rolls for your dragon breath power.

Burning Breath Feat:
- Benefit: Choose one creature hit by your dragon breath. That creature takes ongoing fire damage equal to your con modifier (save ends).

Ancient Soul:
- Benefit: ... Whenever you take damage of the type dealt by your dragon breath (after the damage dealt is reduced by your resistance), you regain the use of your dragon breath if you have already expended it in this encounter.

Hurl Breath:
- Benefit: When you use your dragon breath, you can choose to make it an area burst 2 within 10 squares instead of a close blast 3.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but from my understanding I would be able to cast my dragonbreath as a ranged burst with my character as one of the targets.  I would take essentially the full damage of the dragon breath along with anyone else hit by the attack.  My resistances wouldn't matter because the dragon soul class feature states that "Your arcane powers ignore any target's resistance to that damage type up to the value of your resistance".  Seeing how my dragon breath would now be an arcane power (as per the paragon path), i'd take full damage.  This inturn would trigger Ancient Soul allowing me to regain my dragonbreath for future use.  Now for the important part.  If I select myself to take the ongoing fire damage equal to my con modifier (aka 1 damage) from the burning breath feat, could I choose to not try and save against the effect at the end of my turn to keep regaining my dragonbreath without having to recast it on me each time?

Comment: see also: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/21859/is-resistance-vulnerability-applied-before-damage-is-transferred-with-nusemnees

Comment: Agree with Brian, this is a dupe. There is no option to skip saving. The rest of your description works as you indicate.

Comment: Try getting the [Emblem of Ossandrya](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=133) and really really pissing it off for a -2 to savings throws.

Comment: @waxeagle On a similar line of reasoning, would it be possible to use a spell such as the at-will Lightning Strike for an even more effective combo. Aka, I would hit an enemy, target myself for the creature within 10 squares and take my dex modifier which would hopefully be worth 1 damage.  This would avoid having to hit myself at all with the dragon breath provided everything was lightning based.

Comment: @silversociety that would trigger ancient soul, yeah